# jquery append question

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

In my ASP.net project, I am using a jquery script to update the id=person field in the URL bar:

```
$("form").append("<input type='hidden' name='hiddenEmployeeId' value='" + $('#EmployeeSelected').val() + "' />");
```

This is triggered when the value of the drop-down box changes. It works great, except for the fact that when you change it...it just appends the new id behind the first id, which is exactly what it's supposed to be doing.

However, I only want one id, obviously. What can I do here to accomplish this? Is there a way to CLEAR that first, and then append it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check to see if it exists, if so, set the value. If it doesn't append it:

```
var input = $('input[name=hiddenEmployeeId]');
if(input [0]) {
    input.val($('#EmployeeSelected').val());
} else {
    $("form").append("<input type='hidden' name='hiddenEmployeeId' value='" + $('#EmployeeSelected').val() + "' />");
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how I would use this?

Comment: It's difficult to understand your problem. Is the edit more in line with what you are thinking?

Comment: @Doctor Oreo replace the line of code you've posted with the above lines. However if you inlcuded the input element in the first place you could simplify a lot. Then you'd only need the third line in this answer

Answer (score 1):

Cant you just change the value on the input named 'hiddenEmployeeId' or does it not exists the first time?

```
$("input[name=hiddenEmployeeId]").val($('#EmployeeSelected').val());
```

you can do something like this:

```
$($('input[name=hiddenEmployeeId]')[0] || $('<input type="hidden" name="hiddenEmployeeId">').appendTo("form.selector")[0]).val($('#EmployeeSelected').val());
```

and change the "form.selector" to the form you are working with.

Comment: No, it doesn't exist the first time. And once it is appended, changing the value of #EmployeeSelected won't change what I appended..so if I did this, I would need to run a script when I hit submit that would THEN append the hidden value.

Comment: Okey, well you have to look for if an element with the name hiddenEmployeeId exists or not, if it doesnt exists then create the element, or just use the replaceWith. But you need to to check if an hiddenEmployeeId exists allready or not.